# 2D projectile calculations with consant wind, shown as Bezier curves

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile, simulations

I am developing a 2D artillery shooter game akin to Pocket Tanks or Scorched Earth.

I have all the projectile physics down nice and clean so far. Today, I am going to implement the wind. I am unfortunately having a hard time figuring out how to factor in wind speeds (and wind angles) and determine how they would affect a projectile.

I am using bezier curves because they look like an accurate enough representation of how a projectile will travel, with and without the wind taken into account. My implementation uses three points for the bezier curve.

My issue is figuring out what the 2nd point of the bezier curve should be, so that a projectile shot could look like it's hooking due to the wind. Does anyone have any advice for me on where to go from here?

Comment: why don't you use the actual projectile curve. Perhaps Euler method to create projectile points.

Comment: Would [gamedev.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I don't know anything about bezier curves, this answer is about the exact equations of motion. If it's not what the OP wants, I'll delete it.

I'm not sure what kind of projectile the OP is using, but for a spherical object the velocity vector change due to wind is calculated from the ODE:

$$\frac{d \vec{V}}{dt}= A | \vec{w}-\vec{V}| ( \vec{w}-\vec{V})$$

where $\vec{w}$ is velocity of the wind, $A$ is a constant proportional to the area of the ball, $||$ is the absolute value.

Of course, if you need to take gravity into account, add $\vec{g}$ on the right hand side.

In 2D Cartesian coordinates we obtain a system of equations:

$$\frac{d V_x}{dt}=A(w_x-V_x)\sqrt{(w_x-V_x)^2+(w_y-V_y)^2}$$

$$\frac{d V_y}{dt}=A(w_y-V_y)\sqrt{(w_x-V_x)^2+(w_y-V_y)^2}$$

We can use some kind of approximation (in case when one speed is much larger than the other) or we can solve the equations numerically. After obtaining $V_x(t)$ and $V_y(t)$ we can easily find the trajectory.

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=V_x(t)$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=V_y(t)$$

Source: Carlucci, Donald E. "Ballistics: theory and design of guns and ammunition", CRC Press, 2007, equations (8.100), (8.102) - not this exact formula, but mine is a little more clear.

Also: this does not take into account viscosity of the air! It represents the wind as a flux of solid particles.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}$

Adding into [Yuriy's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/350279/25301), the equation of motion for a projectile in (constant) wind is given by
$$
\frac{\dd{\bf v}}{\dd t}={\bf g}-\frac{c}{m}{\bf v}
$$ 
where $c$ is some positive constant. Breaking this into components, you'll have
$$
\frac{\dd}{\dd t}\left(\begin{array}{c}v_x\\v_y\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}-gv_x/v_t \\ -g\left(1+v_y/v_t\right)\end{array}\right)
$$
where $v_t=mg/c$ is the terminal velocity.

If you integrate these equations twice with respect to time, you'll end up with the $x$-position following,
$$
x\left(t\right)=\frac{v_0v_t}{g}\cos\theta\cdot\left(1-\exp\left[-gt/{v_t}\right]\right)\tag{1}
$$
Similarly, you can solve for $y(t)$ and for the time of flight, $t_f$. If you insert the time of flight equation into (1), you should get the standard formula for range when $v_y\ll v_t$ and 
$$
R=\frac{v_0v_t}{g}\cos\theta
$$
where $v_y\gg v_t$. This limit suggests that you should fire the projectile at *lower* angles to maximize the range (however, care needs to be handled since $v_y=v_0\sin\theta\gg v_t$ is required for this limit).